# How to debug leader issues in kafka 0.80?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've been trying to isolate problems with a small kafka instance. (Have to use kafka because other software which I am not prepared to re-implement depends on it.) This thing only needs to run for a few weeks, but it's not even doing that.

Specifically, here's my current issue:

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic
 test
Created topic "test".
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
This is a message
This is another message[2016-01-20 05:13:56,290] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,296] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,297] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test
 (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,401] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,404] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,404] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test
 (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,507] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,511] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,511] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test
 (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,614] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,618] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,618] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test
 (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,721] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic test -> 
No partition metadata for topic test due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [test]: class kafka.common.LeaderNot
AvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,723] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics test with correlation ids in [0,8] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEv
entHandler)
[2016-01-20 05:13:56,724] ERROR Error in handling batch of 1 events (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:104)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:87)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:254)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:66)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:44)
...
```

In other words, I'm trying the simple test case from the docs, and that's not working right - on a freshly created topic, kafka already has problems with the metadata.

Looking at the kafka logs, the only one which has been recently updated is server.log and it only has info messages about closing sockets.

Looking at zookeeper logs, I do see this:

```
2016-01-20 05:13:16,028 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:57826
2016-01-20 05:13:16,031 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@822] - Connection request from old client /127.0.0.1:57826; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode
2016-01-20 05:13:16,031 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:57826
2016-01-20 05:13:16,032 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x1525d2609e90006 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /127.0.0.1:57826
2016-01-20 05:13:16,164 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1525d2609e90006 type:setData cxid:0x3 zxid:0x452 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics/test Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/topics/test
2016-01-20 05:13:16,179 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@645] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1525d2609e90006 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0x453 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/topics
2016-01-20 05:13:16,190 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@494] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1525d2609e90006
2016-01-20 05:13:16,192 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1007] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:57826 which had sessionid 0x1525d2609e90006
```

But if I understand a 2011 message I saw about this kind of error, this is supposed to be normal, and automatically dealt with.

So...

What should I be doing to isolate and resolve this lack of leader issue? (Note also that the reason I'm trying this test was because my production topic was (a) not writing events to disk and (b) giving me the same kinds of no leader errors when I tried writing test messages to it.)

Comment: Can you run the `describe` command for the topic and post the results ?

Comment: I could - and I was examining kafka-topics describe, but when the problem was happening it impacted all topics, and but also, the problem was resolved as I described above ... wait.... I posted an answer here describing my resolution, but I do not see it now. So maybe something is also wrong here on stack overflow. (The problem was resolved by using kill -9 on the kafka process, and restarting it. Also, /etc/rc?.d started kafka without giving time for zookeeper to first start.) -- anyways, I doubt that the output of describe would be relevant.